# ParaView color map varies between frames, sequential video frames flicker

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing, colormap, paraview

I have almost 1000 2800x2800 images from the output of a CFD simulation which I need to make a video from but they flicker when put into a video.  I can't figure out what color correction would work to best stop them from flickering.  And I really want to process all 1000 images automatically.

One idea I had was to analyze a small corner of the top left of each image compared to the same rectangle in a chosen 'average' image of the 1000 whose overall brightness or gamma (or ??) that I like.  Then I would like to adjust all the images to get their 'sample rectangle' to match the 'average' rectangle.  I think that might work because the flickering is mainly due to changes in the large olivey colour areas of all the images.  But I have no idea what mapping parameter would work best or even how to attempt it automatically.

EDIT: [Here is a link to a draft video with a still unacceptable level of flickering but which better illustrates my issue.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b_Q8Rlf_eMuwqeOnTE1WVxp3OedbtDqu/view)

Here is a sequence of 5 resized images to visualize what the problem is:
[image: 038+000.700 (Small)]

[image: 039+000.800 (Small)]

[image: 040+000.900 (Small)]

[image: 041+001.000 (Small)]

[image: 042+001.100 (Small)]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Dale

Comment: which program? fix the color scale *in that program*... don't correct what you can prevent from happening in the first place. -- any solution to "correct" these pictures would require undoing the color mapping. that's absolutely unreasonable.

Comment: The ParaView program which outputs these images has no way to 'even' them out.  There have been many issues which have been addressed over the years with these LIC surface plots but this issue still persists.  At least now, the image is pretty smooth but there used to be 4 or 6 tiles inside each image that had this issue..

Comment: Would setting the cmap to a fixed limit prevent the flickering from happening? Is your cmap so far depending on the values of each frame?

Comment: I've amended title and tagging to include your additionally revealed information that this is *ParaView*. you really oughta ask in a user support forum for that program.

Comment: I am not using cmap since I do not think it is a color mapping issue (and I am un familiar with how to use cmap for tis issue), I think it is more a histogram shift or gamma or intensity etc.  Perhaps I am wrong.  @Christoph Rackwitz Thanks, it may help but I have scoured the web for ParaView related help and have not had any luck.  The issue is more related to LIC surface plot generation than ParaView color maps generally.  Thanks for adding the image processing tags.

Comment: so either https://discourse.paraview.org/ or https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/issues

Comment: sorry, been there, no help... This is an image processing issue to make different (but similar images) appear not to flicker when put into a video.